# Swift - How do I loop through this array and print each value without subscript error

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, for-loop

I'm trying to loop through this array of HealthKit samples in swift using a standard for in loop, but I keep receiving an error.

Here is the code i'm trying to run:

```
for x in samples! as [HKSample] {
    let data = samples![x] as! HKQuantitySample
    let unit = HKUnit(from: "cal")
    let cal = data.quantity.doubleValue(for: unit)
    print(cal)
}
```

and here is the error it returns:

```
Subscript 'subscript(_:)' requires that 'HKSample' conform to 'RangeExpression'
```

For reference, the same code works when you specify the number of the element in the array you want to access:

```
for x in samples! as [HKSample] {
    let data = samples![0] as! HKQuantitySample
    let unit = HKUnit(from: "cal")
    let cal = data.quantity.doubleValue(for: unit)
    print(cal)
}
```

but as you might expect, this just takes the first element in the array and iterates over and over for the same amount of times as there are elements in the array.

Comment: try `for sample in samples as? [HKQuantitySample] ?? [] {` and then `let cal = sample.quantity.doubleValue(for: HKUnit(from: "cal"))`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Leo Dabus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2303865/leo-dabus)

Just needed reworking a little:

```
for sample in samples as? [HKQuantitySample] ?? [] {
    let unit = HKUnit(from: "cal")
    let cal = sample.quantity.doubleValue(for: unit)
    print(cal)
}
```